# Increase WPF Hyperlink hover time

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

The tool tip for hyperlinks disappears after 5 seconds, but in my application I would prefer to have it stay as long as the mouse hovers.  The following does not work

```
<Hyperlink 
                  ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="10"
                  ToolTipService.ShowDuration="10000"
                  ToolTip="MyTT"
                >
```

All help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can up the length of time, but it's int32 so there is a finite value.

This is milliseconds rather than seconds btw.

The below stays open for quite some time, but not forever.

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink 
                  ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="10"
                  ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2147483647"
                  ToolTip="MyTT"
                >
            www.google.co.uk
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

A tooltip is designed to be ephemeral.
They're intended to appear momentarily to give the user some sort of information or hint and then get out of their way by disappearing.

If you want something that stays open forever they you could consider a popup or maybe a context menu instead.

Comment: Thank you, but your proposed solution is exactly what I had in my question, and it is not working for me.

Comment: It isn't exactly what you had in your question. It's a way bigger number. This works for me, within the limitations of tooltip. So what do you have that's different and you haven't mentioned?